# Python - give time to type answer in input

Tags: loops, time

I created a GUI using tkinter and want to do the following:

1. Play a recording
2. activate and give focus to an input
3. Wait some time to play a new recording and begin again

I want to allow user to hear the recording, let him type in what he heard and then continue with the loop. I have tried using `my_gui.after()`, `time.sleep()`, and `my_gui.update()` as well, but I can't figure it out.

My code looks like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

my_gui = Tk()

for i in range(0,10):
    play_sound(file)
    entry = Entry(my_gui).pack()
    my_gui.update()
    entry.focus()
    my_gui.after(3000,None)

my_gui.mainloop()
```

when I run the code is hard to type some text.

Comment: Where or when is the recording played

Comment: Sorry, I just edited, first it plays the sound, then it creates the entry and gives it focus and finally let the user type the recording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what your looking for, but take a look at this example:

```py
from tkinter import *
import winsound

my_gui = Tk()

my_entries = [] # to append all the entries, so theyr not useless afterwards
counter = 0 #to index the list of entries and give focus to it
tot_entries_num = 9 #total number of entries to be created 

def new():
    global counter
    if counter < tot_entries_num: # if total number of entries are not created
        winsound.PlaySound('Systemhand',winsound.SND_ASYNC) #play a sound or any thing, replace with what you want, but you might need threading.
        my_entries(Entry(my_gui)) #appending an entry to the list
        my_entries[counter].pack() #calling the current item from the list and then pack() on it
        my_entries[counter].insert(0,counter+1) #not necessary, just if you want to see the number of the entries created, remove the +1 to see the entries with index number

        my_entries[counter].focus_force() #get the current item created from the list and give focus to it
        counter += 1 #increase the counter number by 1
        
    rep = my_gui.after(3000,new) # repeat the function for every 3 seconds
    
    if counter > tot_entries_num: #if total number of entries created
        my_gui.after_cancel(rep) # then stop repeating 

new() #call the function initially

my_gui.mainloop()
```

Ive commented the example to make it more understandable on-the-go. Also if you want to use the `get()` on the entry, you would say, `my_entries[n].get()` where `n` is the required entry number starting from 0.